# How to display Progress Bar while macro runs?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a ProgressBar I want to display with % while my macro runs.

I tried the parameters `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` and `UserForm1.Repaint` in my main macro.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()    
    Dim reminder As Long        
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    reminder = 0

    For i = 1 To 200        
        UserForm1.Label2.Width = UserForm1.Label2.Width + 1

        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then        
            reminder = reminder + 1        
            UserForm1.Caption1 = reminder & " % completed"        
        End If

        For j = 1 To 150        
            DoEvents        
        Next j        
    Next i

    Unload UserForm1    
End Sub
```

The UserForm stops on 0% and my main macro runs to the end, then the UserForm with ProgressBar runs from 0 to 100% and closes.

Comment: What should this loop do `For j = 1 To 150`? I recommend to remove that loop and just keep `DoEvents`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, is a "timer" and if I remove it - still not works.

Comment: There are some examples at`CodeReview`. Have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87818/a-reusable-progressindicator/88355#88355 and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62357/progress-bar-form/62365#62365

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not found something what I need:(

Comment: What is Userform1.Caption1? A textbox?

Comment: Did you change the BackColor of Userform1.Label2? If not, you won't be able to see the width changing as it will have the same color as the userform background.

Comment: What is wrong with the`Resuable Progress Indicator except the broken download ([this is an article on it with download at the end](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/01/12/progress-indicator/)) link?

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers, Caption1 - it's a textbox "0% Completed".

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers, please see attached pictures.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO9T4.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/99b7I.png

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, so hard for me:/

Answer (score 0):

That can not work like this. You need 3 functions
one to show the userform progressbar 0 percent.
then you need a function to update your form
end finaly the function to remove the form
This code is NOT tested see the testing code i posted here also !

```
            Dim counter As Long        

            Public Sub UserForm_Activate()    
                counter = 0
                UserForm1.Label2.Width =0
                UserForm.show
            End Sub


            Public Sub UserForm_update()    
                if counter <100 then counter=counter+1
                UserForm1.Label2.Width =  counter
                DoEvents        
            end sub


            Public Sub UserForm_close()    
                counter = 0
                UserForm.hide
            End Sub


            'somewhere in a module or class

            sub calculate
                call UserForm_Activate()    
                for i=0 to 100
                   call UserForm_update()
                   'whatever 
   '  Sleep (200) if this very handy OS call is included somewhere
                next
                call UserForm_close
            end sub
```

Comment: Make form with 3 Butons and test the thing sub by sub. The first 3 subs as the counter has to live in the progressbarform and the calculate thing in some module.BTW Doesnt Work is not a answer. What does not work ? Does the progressbar doesnt show up ? Is there a error message ?

Comment: It's doesn't work like it need to work. With my code what I was written upper I get the same result (UserForm is working, but stacks in 0% and waiting for the macro while macro is running to the end, and only after that UserForm starting to work. Maybe I did something wrong while tested your code.

Comment: This code IS working. Create a new worksheet and put my code inside. Be careful to name the few controls and userforms accordingly. Make the forms non modal. I am 100% sure that your call to your update is on the wrong place or your counter variable is not proper addressed or reset to zero. If you can not make this tiny thing go to work i would suggest to forget about the progressbar until you are a bit more familar with VBA.  BTW https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.statusbar is also a nice and simple way to show a progress. Using it is very simple

Comment: Ah yes might be :) *grin*. I use a lib to call the windows syssleep api. Such things are in my standard excel xla loaded on startup - so i forget :) Take a look here : https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/pausing-or-delaying-vba-using-wait-sleep-or-a-loop or just coment the call out.

Answer (score 0):

WORKING: 
I create two NON MODAL! Forms NAMED "progressbar" 
( with 1 Textbox NAMED counter) 
and "tester "
(with 3 Buttons NAMED count hide and show)

the code in progressbar:

```
            Dim count As Long

            Public Sub progressbar_show()
                count = 0
                progressbar.Show
            End Sub


            Public Sub progressbar_update()
                If count < 100 Then count = count + 1
                progressbar.counter.Text = Str(count)
                DoEvents
            End Sub


            Public Sub progressbar_close()
                counter = 0
                progressbar.hide
            End Sub
```

The code in tester: (calls routines in form progressbar)

```
            Private Sub count_Click()
                Call progressbar.progressbar_update
            End Sub

            Private Sub hide_Click()
                Call progressbar.progressbar_close
            End Sub

            Private Sub show_Click()
                Call progressbar.progressbar_show
            End Sub
```

Works as designed.
on the click button the textbox will be updated on each click.
Please note HOW i call the functions from on form to the other form. The form name has to be included. The name of the controls have also to match. Its a good idea to rename the controls and forms. I made a autocad VBA with has 1700 controls. Its not the fun after some weeks 
to imagine what commandbutton_762  actuelly may do ;)

Comment: Sorry, but i don't need a UserForm that updates with CommandButtons.
I need command form what I can call from my main macro (putting in the beginning of the macro line ProgressBar.Show) and it's open and run a UserForm ProgressBar with percentage updating and macro in the same time without any buttons click.

Comment: This command buttons are ment as demo, They are not needed. They just schall show you how it is working.  Take the code of them out and copy their working code inside your macro. I placed also a rewritten and *tested* version here in. The code is totally basic that is why i suggest to give a bit more afford to this. I try to help but I am not willing to making other peoples homework.